# How to get best mark for each Student

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't find a solution although it should be easy one.

I have some students and all I need is to get the highest mark of each one in Math.

```
TableName: Students.
Columns:
Name Mark
John 90
John 84
John 92
John 60
Yan  75
Yan  88
Yan  60
```

I want to get this results:

```
Name Mark
John 92
Yan  88
```

I have tried to do `top 1`, but it gives me only one student. I need to do somehow `top 1` on each student, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help me to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using an aggregate function and a group by - `select name, max(mark) from students group by name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select Name, max(Mark) AS Mark
from Students
group by Name
```